# Handle URL query parameters in Play! SQL statement?

Tags: url, playframework, extjs4, query-string

I am testing a Ext JS application (Client Side) and Play Framework (Service Side).
I am using a grid in Ext JS with **pagination**.

The pagination part requires to send URL Query Parameters to my Play! server. This is no big deal, but how to process these parameters in the SQL Statement??

Example:

First request:

```
http://myDomain:9000/GetUsers?_dc=123456789&page=1&start=0&limit=25
```

Second reqeust:

```
http://myDomain:9000/GetUsers?_dc=123456789&page=2&start=25&limit=25
```

**My thoughts:**
Normally in SQL you can set the **TOP** results:

```
SELECT TOP 25 FROM USERS
```

But how to translate the second request into a Sql query?

Thank you for taking time to help me out!

**======>>** 
EDIT: I am developing on SQL Server 2008, but I want this working on Sql Server 2005 or higher and Oracle 9 and higher :-)

Comment: It sounds like you are using SQL Server: this might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server

Comment: Yes Femi! That is correct! That is the same question. I'am developing on SQL Server but I will test it also on Oracle as well. Thank you, I will update my question once i get this working.

Comment: If you're using Play, then why are you using SQL directly? Shouldn't you be working with JPA?

Comment: @itsadok; I tried JPA but just could not work with it. Mainly because I need to spent some time to learn it :-). I have just ordered the Play! book so it is going the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the Play! framework, what you should do is have a proper [model](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/model), with entities representing your SQL tables. Then receiving a range of results is [built in](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jpa#finding):

```
// 25 max users start at 25
List<User> users = User.all().from(25).fetch(25);
```

You should also look at the [pagination module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/paginate-head/home). I haven't tested it, but it looks like exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
WITH Query_1 AS (
    SELECT
        Field1, Field2, etc
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field1, Field2, etc) AS RowID
    FROM Table
    WHERE x=y
)
SELECT * FROM Query_1 WHERE RowID >= @start
AND RowID < @start + @limit
```

Of course ROW_NUMBER didn't exist back in SQL 2000 but since you've not told us *which* SQL you're working with I'm assuming something newer.