# Complex SQL pagination Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I am doing pagination for my data using the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server) question.

I need to be using this solution for a more complex query now. Ie. the `SELECT` inside the bracket has joins and aggregate functions.

This is that solution I'm using as a reference:

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol1, SortCol2, ...) AS RowNum
    FROM Table
    WHERE <whatever>
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= @Offset
AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit
```

The query that I need to incorporate into the above solution:

```
SELECT users.indicator, COUNT(*) as 'queries' FROM queries
INNER JOIN calls ON queries.call_id = calls.id
INNER JOIN users ON calls.user_id = users.id
WHERE queries.isresolved=0 AND users.indicator='ind1'
GROUP BY users.indicator ORDER BY queries DESC
```

How can I achieve this? So far I've made it work by removing the `ORDER BY queries DESC` part and putting that in the line `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS RowNum`, but when I do this it doesn't allow me to order by that column ("Invalid column name 'queries'.").

What do I need to do to get it to order by this column?

**edit**: using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC . It works on MySQL ... not sure about SQL Server 2008

Comment: why the hell didn't i try that. works, thanks a lot. 8 mins before i can mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think queries your alias name for count(*) column
then use like this

```
SELECT users.indicator, COUNT(*) as 'queries' FROM queries
INNER JOIN calls ON queries.call_id = calls.id
INNER JOIN users ON calls.user_id = users.id
WHERE queries.isresolved=0 AND users.indicator='ind1'
GROUP BY users.indicator ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

http://oops-solution.blogspot.com/2011/11/string-handling-in-javascript.html