# Adding pagination to list from database

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have some basic c# code which connects to a database and prints out all rows returned i.e:

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
{
    using (command = new SqlCommand("select * from table1", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Div1.InnerHtml += reader["col1"].ToString() + "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add pagination to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Gridview control. it is more easier, rather than building your own pagination method.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  allowpaging="True">
    <Columns>
     //your all boundfield columns 
    </Columns>
</asp:gridView>
```

for Paging, you can use OnPageIndexChanging event handler. [Page Index Changing.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onpageindexchanging.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK with DataReader, you will need to "Skip" `(PageNumber - 1) * PageSize` rows by just looping reader.Read().

As an alternative, you could do the [pagination in your SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server) - this way you return only the records that you need (although you will need to do additional work to determine the total number of records that match the filter)