# The SQL Server equivalent for the MySQL Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)

this is a mysql query

```
SELECT email FROM emailTable LIMIT 9,20 WHERE id=3
```

how do you write it in SQL Server (2008)?

do I have to write

```
SELECT TOP 9,20 email FROM emailTable WHERE id=3
```

?
Thank you for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server

Comment: Thank you but it was no use, since It doesnt answer my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
      SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY email) as rowNum 
      FROM tableName
) sub 
WHERE rowNum > 9 
  AND rowNum <= 9 + 20 
  AND id = 3
```

---

### [DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61406)

Comment: I fixed your query to match the OP's behaviour. In MySQL, the syntax is `LIMIT offset, rowcount`. That means you have to do `rownum > offset and rownum <= offset + rowcount`

Comment: So, I can't see the email column

Comment: @AdaBell'hMonTrésor, No you can select the columns you want in the select clause, see the demo page .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to achieve the same outcome.

e.g. to get rows 1 to 10:

```
;WITH results AS
(    
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourColumn ASC) AS RowNo,
        email
    FROM emailTable
)

SELECT * 
FROM results
WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

**Edit:**
condensed into 1 statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourColumn ASC) AS RowNo,
        email
    FROM emailTable
) x
WHERE x.RowNo BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: thank you AdaTheDev but can you do it basically? I mean just select email for 20 first users whose id=3, starting by the 9th... maybe you catch me well

Comment: It isn't as straight forward as there isn't support for LIMIT. There are other variations of this, but none as as "basic" as LIMIT. e.g. the above could be condensed into 1 SELECT statement, as updated in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Limit with offset in sql server:

```
SELECT email FROM emailTable WHERE id=3
OFFSET 8 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 12 ROWS ONLY;
```

//offset - no. of skipped rows

//next - required no. of next rows

Update: This is working but sql server 2012 onwards

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012 (not yet released)

Comment: Offset is no. of rows want to skip. He want results from 9