# Getting huge data from sql server with php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table call Access with 200 thounsand entries and I need get all the data and display it on a map.
The schema of the data base is:

```
long    |  lat    |  service
12.00   | 34.33   |    3
133.32  | 32.4213 |    5
-58.3   | -3.3233 |    10
```

If I try the query:

```
SELECT long, lat, service FROM Access;
```

on SQL SERVER Console I get all the data, and works great, but if I try it with this php code:

```
$result = mssql_query($query) or die('Query Failed ' . mssql_error());
```

I get nothing. No errors and no data. 
I increased the memory limit on my php.ini and I set it to 1024M but I'm getting the same output,no errors and no data.

There are any way to get thousands of entries from a data base on a php array? What are I'm doig bad?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - still getting no errors? As a side note, 200,000 points on one map? I can't believe that would be much use to anyone...

Comment: You should never read huge data structures into memory, regardless of the programming language being used, and especially not with PHP which uses a lot of memory for a given data structure.  Use LIMIT and OFFSET to read the data in chunks.

Comment: @GordonM SQL Server has no LIMIT or OFFSET, although the principle of what you say is sound. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+limit).

Comment: DaveRandom, I try error_reporting and ini_set right now. By the way, I'm using clustered map javascript to display all points. GordonM, sql server has no LIMIT. Thanks for your awswers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mssql_query() doesn't return any data, it returns a result resource on success. Have a look to the documentation: http://php.net/mssql_query
You must also use another function such as http://php.net/mssql_fetch_assoc to retrieve all your data.

```
mssql_connect(...); // put valid server/login/password here
$result = mssql_query($query) or die('Query Failed ' . mssql_error());
while($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // use $r['long'], $r['lat']...to access the data of the fetched record
}
```

The while() loop is neccessary to fetch all records, one record for each call of mssql_fetch_assoc().