# How to mimic SELECT ... LIMIT, OFFSET in OpenEdge SQL?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

It's a common thing in most SQL implementations to be able to select a "sliding window" subset of all the rows returned in a query.  A common use case for this is pagination.  For example, say I have a search page with 10 results on each page.  For implementations that support `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` keywords, the query used to return results for each page would be as follows: page one would use `SELECT ... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0`, page 2 would use `SELECT ... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`, page 3 would use `SELECT ... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20`, etc. (note that the `OFFSET` takes effect before the `LIMIT`).

Anyway, I'm trying to mimic this functionality in OpenEdge's SQL engine.  I've already figured out that `SELECT TOP` is basically equivalent to `LIMIT`, however I can't find anything similar to `OFFSET` (I don't think there is an *exact* equivalent).  SQL Server and Oracle also lack an `OFFSET`, but they have a pseudocolumn called `ROWCOUNT` and `ROWNUM`, respectively, that can be used to mimic the behavior using nested selects (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2135449/215168) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/470571/215168)).

In the [10.2B SQL Reference](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dmsrf/dmsrf.pdf) doc, p49 there is a subsection entitled **TOP clause** that says at the bottom

> `SELECT TOP` is the functional equivalent of the Oracle `ROWNUM`
>   functionality. Note that `SELECT TOP` is defined simply in terms of a
>   limit on the result set size, and the optimizer determines how to use
>   this limit for best data access. Thus, `SELECT TOP` does not have all
>   the "procedural rules" used to define the meaning of the Oracle `ROWNUM`
>   phrase.

However, this seems to be inaccurate as according to `TOP`'s syntax it cannot be used as a predicate like `ROWNUM` can (e.g. I can't say `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE TOP > 5 AND TOP < 10`).  So `TOP` is **not** functionally equivalent to `ROWNUM`.

Is there any way to mimic `OFFSET`, or am I out of luck?

Comment: I think, this is not supported in Progress SQL. Do you can use a PK-ID to find, which row was selected in last SELECT TOP 10? Than you can write in the next SELECT something like SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Cutsomer.CustID > lastcustomerid TOP 10...

Comment: @firhang Yes, you are correct that it is not supported. The PK solution works for when queries are constructed with PK's *and* I want to retrieve them in PK-order, but that will not always be the case so it doesn't work for a general solution (which is what I need).  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenEdge 11.2 added support for [`OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge112/oe112html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Data%20Management/SQL%20Reference/05dmsrfStmt.132.45.html#480988) to SQL `SELECT` queries; versions of OpenEdge below 11.2 do not support `OFFSET`/`FETCH`.

From the [11.2 product documentation](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-107875) "SQL Reference" document:

```
The OFFSET clause specifies the number of rows to skip, before starting to return rows
from the query expression. The FETCH clause specifies the number of rows to return,
after processing the OFFSET clause.
```

It's worth noting that the **`TOP` and `OFFSET`/`FETCH` clauses are mutually exclusive** - `TOP` cannot be used in a query that uses `OFFSET` or `FETCH`.

### Example queries from the documentation:

Skip the first 10 rows and return the rest of the qualified rows:

```
SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,custID,filler
FROM dbo.Orders OFFSET 10;
```

Return the first 10 rows without skipping any:

```
SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,custID,filler
FROM dbo.Orders
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, OrderID DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Return rows 51 through 60 in the result set of the query:

```
SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,custID,filler
FROM dbo.Orders
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, OrderID DESC
OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```