# How do I join to a first row in OpenEdge SQL?

Tags: sql, openedge

Joining to first row in SQL should be as trivial as simply joining to an inner select

```
select so_nbr, sod_line last_line
  from so_mstr
  join sod_det on sod_det.rowid = (select top 1 sod_det.rowid
                                     from sod_det
                                    where sod_nbr = so_nbr
                                    order by sod_line desc) x
 where so_ord_date > curdate() - 60
```

Unfortunately I get: `Error code -20302, SQL state HY000: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] TOP clause used in unsupported context. (13694)`

Note, I am stuck on OE10.1C and will not be able to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Abe Voelker's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982345/456814):

> OpenEdge 11.2 added support for [`OFFSET` and `FETCH`
>   clauses](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge112/oe112html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Data%20Management/SQL%20Reference/05dmsrfStmt.132.45.html#480988)
>   to SQL `SELECT` queries; versions of OpenEdge below 11.2 do not
>   support `OFFSET`/`FETCH`.
>
> From the [11.2 product
>   documentation](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-107875)
>   "SQL Reference" document:
>
> ```
> The OFFSET clause specifies the number of rows to skip, before starting to return rows
> from the query expression. The FETCH clause specifies the number of rows to return,
> after processing the OFFSET clause.
> ```
>
> It's worth noting that the **`TOP` and `OFFSET`/`FETCH` clauses are
>   mutually exclusive** - `TOP` cannot be used in a query that uses
>   `OFFSET` or `FETCH`.

Try this

```
  SELECT so_nbr,sod_line As last_line
  FROM so_mstr
       JOIN sod_det ON sod_det.rowid = (SELECT sod_det.rowid 
                                        FROM sod_det WHERE sod_nbr = so_nbr
                                        ORDER BY sod_line Desc 
                                        FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) x
  WHERE so_ord_date > curdate() - 60
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are on 10.1C and will not have the opportunity to upgrade. Is there a way to achieve this on prior versions of OpenEdge?