# SQL Server : is there any alternate for TOP clause?

Tags: sql-server, database, jqgrid, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)

I am working on a table which currently contains 2500 rows, and will be much more and more in future.

I am using jqgrid to display the records from the database .

Whenever the grid is loading, I am retrieving the `top 500` rows from the database. However when I am started using pagination in the grid, the number of records is adding.

Example : first the number of rows is `TOP 100`, then going onto the next page its increased to `TOP 200` and so on in the query.

Now I want a solution to avoid this issue such that I can limit the rows instead of retrieving top n rows based on the grid. Say using a range or `LIMIT`

Example

When I am navigating to next page in grid, instead of `TOP 200` rows I want to fetch rows from 101 to 200

```
 select top 500
        exe.id,
        bat.BName,
        bat.tid,
        bat.freq,
        exe.status,
        exe.Msg,
        exe.time,
        exe.Fi
    from
       XXX exe,
        YYY bat 
    where
        exe.id=bat.id   
    order by     
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
        exe.time,
        120) DESC,
        exe.status,
        exe.id DESC
```

Please guide me in this, as I am new to jQGrid and not much aware how to handle this DB related stuff

I also referred few links in Stackoverflow but can't understand

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have this tagged with both sql-server and oracle which RDBMS do you want a solution for?

Comment: sorry i want it for sqlserver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), the `row_number()` is not assigned until you query the data so if you want to retrieve the data by the `row_number()` value, then you will need to use `CTE` or a sub-select to get the value for use in a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  select  exe.id,
        bat.BName,
        bat.tid,
        bat.freq,
        exe.status,
        exe.Msg,
        exe.time,
        exe.Fi,
        row_number() over(order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), exe.time, 120) DESC,
                   exe.status, exe.id DESC) rn
  from XXX exe,
       YYY bat 
  where exe.id=bat.id  
) x
WHERE rn between 101 and 200
```

I would also suggest a change in your `JOIN` syntax to use ANSI syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  select  exe.id,
        bat.BName,
        bat.tid,
        bat.freq,
        exe.status,
        exe.Msg,
        exe.time,
        exe.File,
        row_number() over(order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), exe.time, 120) DESC,
                   exe.status, exe.id DESC) rn
  from XXXexe
  INNER JOIN  YYY bat 
     ON exe.id=bat.id  
) x
WHERE rn between 101 and 200
```

Comment: thank you , so first time am retrieving 500 records , from the next time i have to pass values dynamically to between clause right ?

Comment: You can create a stored proc that you just pass in the parameters for each set that you want to retrieve. No need to return 500 records if you don't want them all. :)

Comment: @john conde thanks for the edit, I guess I didn't realize I cut off the first character when copy/pasting. :)

Comment: @bluefeet, better a first character in "You" then missing a character in a query!