# How can i select all other records without top five records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Location    TotalRevenue    LocationID

Orugodawatta    10059135.78 OR
Kohuwala    7058537.73  KH
Koswaththa  6717136.02  KW
Havelock Town   5748932.59  HT
Negombo         5193678.33  NG
Induruwa    3017552.74  IA
Absdhku         2254281.21      AB
```

I have a  table in sql server 2008. how can i select all other rows without top 5 records?
if my table had 100 records i can selece all other 95 records without top 5 records. please help me

Comment: What do you mean "without the top 5 records" ? Only the last 95 of the rows, or the first 95 ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server

Comment: SELECT  top(5)Location, SUM(SellingPrice) AS 'Total Revenue', LocationID
FROM         BI_LocWiseTopItems
WHERE     (GRNDate BETWEEN '' AND GETDATE())
GROUP BY Location, LocationID
ORDER BY 'Total Revenue' desc  this is my query. it is returining only top 5 records. bt i want only all othre records without top 5. number of records are dynamically changing

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LOCATION NOT IN (SELECT TOP 5 LOCATION FROM MyTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT Count(*) - 5 FROM tableName WHERE YOUR_WHERE_CLAUSE) * 
  FROM tableName 
 WHERE YOUR_WHERE_CLAUSE
 ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
EXCEPT (SELECT TOP(5)* FROM tableName  )
```

Your entire query. Have a try

```
SELECT Location,[Total Revenue],LocationID
FROM
  (
    SELECT Location, SUM(SellingPrice) AS 'Total Revenue', LocationID 
    FROM BI_LocWiseTopItems 
    WHERE (GRNDate BETWEEN '' AND GETDATE()) 
    GROUP BY Location, LocationID ORDER BY 'Total Revenue' desc 
  ) AS temp
EXCEPT  (
    SELECT top(5)Location, SUM(SellingPrice) AS 'Total Revenue', LocationID 
    FROM BI_LocWiseTopItems 
    WHERE (GRNDate BETWEEN '' AND GETDATE()) 
    GROUP BY Location, LocationID ORDER BY 'Total Revenue' desc 
 )
```

Comment: Overkill. Upgrade to MSSQL 2011, which has an `OFFSET` clause :)

Comment: MSSQL 2011? It is 2012. But he didn;t mentioned the version

Comment: And upgrading SQL server (with all the costs associated) is not overkill?

Comment: @Nithesh He did, 2008 does not have an `OFFSET`... @Mr47 Depends. If this is a one-time query, then yes, totally. But if it is meant to be used repeatedly, maybe by an application, then upgrading -- or maybe moving away from MSSQL altogether -- may be the right choice.

Comment: Did you try, your result will always be empty, wether the table is empty or if not: EXISTS will return `true` and nothing will be selected

Comment: Updated the answer with except. I think this will work properly

Answer (score 0):

suppose you get Top 5 records by Query

```
select Top 5 * 
from Table_name 
order by Location desc
```

So to get your 95 records

```
select Top 100 * 
from Table_name 
order by Location desc
except
select Top 5 * 
from Table_name 
order by Location desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all in first CTE, select top 5 in second, and just use `EXCEPT` :

```
WITH CTE_ALL AS 
(
    SELECT 
            Location ,
            SUM(SellingPrice) AS [Total Revenue] ,
            LocationID
    FROM    BI_LocWiseTopItems
    WHERE   ( GRNDate BETWEEN '' AND GETDATE() )
    GROUP BY Location ,
            LocationID
)
, CTE_TOP5 AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM CTE_ALL 
    ORDER BY [Total Revenue]
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_ALL
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM CTE_TOP5
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea918/3)** - Simplified for CTE

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH top5 AS (
  SELECT TOP 5
         Location
       , TotalRevenue
       , LocationID
  FROM   your_table
  ORDER
      BY TotalRevenue DESC
)
SELECT Location
     , TotalRevenue
     , LocationID
FROM   your_table
EXCEPT
SELECT Location
     , TotalRevenue
     , LocationID
FROM   top5
```