# Why can't I query OFFSET/ FETCH query on my SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to run this query on my SQL Server as follows:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1

But it can't recognize the OFFSET and so shows ERROR?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_MatchDetail
ORDER BY MatchDetailID
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: The syntax you show was apparently introduced in SQL Server 2012, so if you're using SQL Server 2008 per your tag, that's the problem. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2135418/157957) for alternatives.

Comment: ok thanx is there any equivalent Syntax for MSSQL 2008 R2?

Comment: See the answers to the question I linked to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OFFSET FETCH is a new feature added to Sql Server 2012 and does not exist in Sql Server 2008.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      12.0.1524.0



This is my MSSQL Info as above with MSSQL 2014 CTP2 still OFFSET keyword is not valid Why?

Comment: OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS only.

Comment: Add Only keyword at the end.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz Does it work with SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)? I always get 'Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'' error

Comment: @ArianSharifian having same issue in SSMS 2012 :/

Comment: Check the only at the end , the syntax should be true .

Comment: Please Consider that it should appear after order by clause.

Answer (score 17):

Please be aware you will get an error even in 2014 if you don't have an order by. The offset must follow an order by statement.

Comment: Yes this was the problem with me. Thanks