# Implement Paging With SQL Server 2008 in MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, t-sql

Currently I have a frontend JQuery datatable (which is set to serverside), and my stored procedure (SP) is returning all of the data as below:

```
Select ID, FullName, FullAddress, Coord
From Names n
inner join Person p ON n.ID = p.PID
inner join Address a ON n.AddressID = a.ID
order by FullName
```

I want to achieve paging and restrict to only 200 rows of data at a time. I can pass in the page no (page no begins from 0) as parameter to SP i.e. for example if the pageno = 0 the first 200 rows should only be returned. if page no = 1 rows from position 200 to 400 will be returned and so on.

How can I change the above SP to achieve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2135449/1524085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to retrieve data based on each page request , you can use the following stored proc:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE GetDataPageWise                      // Name of the stored procedure
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

Select Row_Number() Over
(
 ID
) as RowNumber
ID, FullName, FullAddress, Coord
into #Results// #Results is the temporary table that we are creating
From Names n
inner join Person p ON n.ID = p.PID
inner join Address a ON n.AddressID = a.ID
order by FullName
SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)FROM #Results

SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results                      // Dropping the temporary table results as it is not required furthur
END
GO
```

Here, you need to send the parameters current **page index** that you are requesting , **page size** that is number of records per page

Hope this helps..

Comment: Avinash can you modify the above to include my Select statement and the joins from my question above. thanks