# Paginating a `View Cart` Page using PHP

Tags: php, session, caching, pagination, shopping-cart

I am trying to paginate my PHP page by ten results per page. Currently the page shows all results at once. I did look up some tutorials on pagination but I cannot seem to figure out how to implement them into the current PHP page. The PHP page is called `view_cart.php` and it essentially retrieves the cached products that were added by the user via a shopping cart page and displays them on this page. I am just looking for a few hints to point me in the right direction, not for someone to do my work for me.

This is the `view_cart.php` page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
    {
        $total = 0;
        echo '<form method="post" action="PAYMENT-GATEWAY">';
        echo '<ul>';
        $cart_items = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
           $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
           $queryy = "SELECT TOP 1 product_name,product_desc, price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code'";
           $results = mssql_query($queryy, $mysqli);
           $obj = mssql_fetch_object($results);

            echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
            echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
            echo '<div class="p-price">'.$currency.$obj->price.'</div>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
            echo '<h3>'.$obj->product_name.' (Code :'.$product_code.')</h3> ';
            echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
            $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_desc.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
            $cart_items ++;

        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '<span class="check-out-txt">';
        echo '<strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong>  ';
        echo '</span>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '<a href="checkout.php">Checkout</a>';

    }else{
        echo 'Your Cart is empty';
    }


?>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton');
?>
<?php echo date("D M d, Y G:i a"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the `config.php` page code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mssql_connect('gd','Gad','Rdgaf!');  
$objConnectee = mssql_select_db('Gdaddf',$mysqli ); 
?>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will have url parameters: start and count.
2. Use them in the sql query, like `LIMIT $_GET['start'], $_GET['count']`
3. The last thing is to render links to the "Next" and "Previous" page. (and to "First", "Last", 1,2,3,4....). Those links will include parameters start and count.

For example, the "Next" link will contain url with parameters:

```
"view_cart.php?start=" . ($_GET['start'] + $_GET['count']) . "&count=" . $_GET['count']
```

Beware of the total record count to not overflow.

Comment: I have something like this on my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409981/shopping-carts-view-cart-items-page-is-not-paginating-properly and I seem to be doing what you are saying but I am still not getting the results. Thanks for the hints, though.