# Fetch data from table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table named `"Orders"` with **1-1000** rows and 3 columns (`S.no`, `Order` and `Status`). I need to fetch `Order` from `50-1000` which has its `Status` as `"Cancelled"`. How can i do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Orders with S.no range 50-1000. You can take it as OrderID

Comment: In that case, all four answers below are correct. Just pick whatever it easiest for you to maintain (if your data were huge, you might want to look at performance differences of BETWEEN vs >= AND <, and make sure none apply... but this is not much data. Just pick what's easiest to maintain

Comment: @Manish Sahni : Have you succeeded?

Comment: @evanv: `BETWEEN` has no difference in performance vs. using `>=` and `<=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Logic operator*:

```
SELECT Order 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Status = 'Cancelled'
  AND (S.no > 50 AND S.no < 1000)
```

`BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT Order 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Status = 'Cancelled'
  AND (S.no BETWEEN 50 and 1000)
```

Comment: Can it be done using BETWEEN. Will it fetch 50 and 1000 inclusive?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE (S.no BETWEEN 50 AND 1000) AND (Status = 'Cancelled')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Will this fetch rows 50 and 1000 inclusive or just values between them?

Comment: It will get 50 and 1000 also. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Comment: thanks..i think BETWEEN is the way to go if performance is considered. I wish i could accept your answer as well but @Notulysses marked the beginning with the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from orders
 where no between 50 and 1000
   and status = 'Cancelled'
```

Assuming you meant to say that the column was named "no". S.no would not be a valid column name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you don't have access to Limit and Offset (unless that's changed in the last year or so, in which case please someone correct me).

There's a really nice generalizable solution discussed here: [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)

I'd definitely take a look at that. If indeed your s_no values range from 1-1000, then the solution above by Notulysses should work just fine. But if you don't have so_no between 1-1000  (or in some other easy to filter way) then check out the solution linked to above. If you can what Notulysses recommended, go for it. If you need a generalizable solution, the one above is very good. I've also copied it below, for reference

```
  ;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol1, SortCol2, ...) AS RowNum
    FROM Table
    WHERE <whatever>
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= @Offset
AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit
```

Comment: Milica's answer is also good, if your so_no is easily filterable like that (or if you have an auto increment column that accurately orders your order numbers)