# comparing two tables to make sure they are same row by row and column by column on SQl server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am comparing two tables to make sure they are same row by row and column by column on SQl server.

```
      SELECT  *
        FROM t1, t2
        WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
      AND t1.column3 = t2.column3 AND t1.column4 != t2.column4
```

The tables are vey large, more than 100 million.

I got error:

```
    ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  9434 : Not enough memory for merge-style join
```

Are there better ways to do this comparison.

thanks !

Comment: just out of curiosity how much memory do you have on your server?

Answer (score 1):

A much efficient way of checking the row by row difference will be using Exists operator.

Something like this....

```
SELECT  *
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM  t2 
                  WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1 
                    AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
                    AND t1.column3 = t2.column3 
                    AND t1.column4 = t2.column4
                  )
```

Comment: same error: ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  9434 : Not enough memory for merge-style join, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could try `EXCEPT` [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM t1
EXCEPT
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM t2
```

Comment: same error: ERROR [HY000] ERROR: 9434 : Not enough memory for merge-style join, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What if you try an INNER JOIN (and not select all the data from both tables)?

```
SELECT  t1.column4, t2.column4
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
  AND t1.column3 = t2.column3
WHERE t1.column4 != t2.column4
```

Do you want to identify all the rows that are different or just identify IF there are any rows that are different?

Comment: same error: ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  9434 : Not enough memory for merge-style join, thanks !

Comment: check IF there are any rows that are different

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this: first, I assume you have primary keys on both tables. When you join those tables, the best way to join is using primary key fields, not all of them:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

then you can compare those tables field-by-field without overloading sql:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.field1 <> t2.field1 ot t1.field2 <> t2.field2 .....
```

the resulting records would be mismatches.

the code I wrote here is conceptual, I personally didn't run it on sql, so you might need to adjust

Comment: "outer join" will make it run out of memory. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

All of the above are good suggestions (My first try would be `SELECT * FROM t1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM t2`), but you indicate they all give the same out of memory error. Therefore I must conclude your tables are simply too large to perform the operation you desire *all in one go*. You'll have to run the query in stages, using a technique like one of the ones from ["Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server) I'd start with something like [this (SQL Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/425c6/1):

```
DECLARE @offset INT = 0
SELECT TOP 50000000 * 
  FROM (
        SELECT *, 
               ROW_NUMBER() over (order by column1) AS r_n_n 
          FROM t1
        ) xx 
  WHERE r_n_n >= @offset
EXCEPT
 SELECT TOP 50000000 * 
   FROM (
         SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() over (order by column1) AS r_n_n 
           FROM t2
        ) xx 
  WHERE r_n_n >= @offset
```

Then you can increment `@offset` by the amount of `TOP n` and do it again. This will likely involve some trial and error to find the limit for the `TOP n` clause that will run to completion rather than throw an error. I'd start with half, then try quarters, eighths, *etc.* as necessary.

Comment: do I need to sort the tables before I do the comparison ? Otherwise, how ot make sure the top 5000000 rows should be compared ? thanks !

Comment: The result set is ordered by whatever you specify in the [`ORDER BY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.100).aspx) argument in the [`OVER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.100).aspx) clause of `ROW_NUMBER()` as a side effect. As long as it's the same for both tables, it should be fine.