# Pagination from servlet results using jquery (no php or jsp)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

I have an html page (results.html) which shows all the contents of a table retrieved with a servlet using an ajax call. I need the result to be paginated.

Result of the servlet is printed in the div below. I want this to be paginated using jquery, i don't want to refresh the whole page

**results.html**

```html
<div id="result2" class="container" style="margin: auto;"></div>
```

**fetch.js**

```js
function GetCategory(category) {
 j.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : '../auctionsDisplay',
  data : {
   "type" : "1",
   "category" : category
  },
  success : function(data) {
   j("#result2").html(data);
  }
 });

}
```

And this is my doPost in the servlet
**fetchServ.java**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String result = "";

    try {
        Connection con = DBConnection.getCon();

        String type=request.getParameter("type");
        String category = request.getParameter("category");



        ResultSet rs=null;
        PreparedStatement ps;
        String query;

        query = "select id, name, price from " + category;
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();


        int i;
        result = "";
        boolean flag = rs.next();
        result += "<div class='container'><div class='row'><h1>"+category+"</h1></div>";
        while (flag) {  
            result+="<div class='row'>";
            i = 0;
            while (i < 4 && flag) {
                ps = con.prepareStatement("select highestBidder, ends from auctions where itemId=?");
                ps.setString(1, rs.getString("id"));

                ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
                rs2.next();
                String price = rs.getString("price");
                if (rs2.getString("highestBidder") != null)
                    price = rs2.getString("highestBidder");
                String id=rs.getString("id");
                result += "<div class='col-md-3' portfolio-item>";
                result += "<div class='w3-container w3-hover-shadow w3-center'>" + "<h2 style='height:60px'>" + rs.getString("name")
                        + "</h2><div class='w3-card-20' style='width:100%'>"
                        + "<input id="+id+" type='image' src='../img/portfolio/w3.jpg' data-toggle='modal' "
                        + "data-target='#MoreInfo'style='width:90%;'>"
                        + "<div class='w3-container w3-center responsive'>"
                        + "<p style='padding:5px;'>Highest Bid: " + price + "\u20ac <br> " + "Ends at: "
                        + rs2.getString("ends") + "<p></div></div></div></div>";

                flag = rs.next();
                i++;
            }

            result += "</div>";
        }
        result+="</div>";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.println(result);
}
```

I have tried a lot of things but they did not work in accordance with my code
I would appreciate some code (working code if possible) or accurate instructions on how to achieve pagination through jquery. (yes i can change my code and place the items in a table for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you working code, so please stop reading if that is what you want.

If you're using MySQL you can pass the limit and offset variables to your query [Limit and offset examples](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

You would modify your jquery by passing those variables via your ajax request.  Limit being the number of rows/page and the offset being the page number times the rows/page.  So, if you were on page 3 and the rows/page were 10, you would set the offset to 21st row (which is the 20th row for MySQL, since it counts from 0).

```
$('.pagination').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default click behavior for a link
    limit = 10;                         //hard code the limit (rows/page)
    offset = $(this).data('offset');    //get the offset for the link clicked
    $.ajax({                            //ajax
        type : 'POST',
        url : '../auctionsDisplay',
        data : {
        "type"      : "1",
        "category"  : category,
        "limit"     : limit,        //set limit
        "offset"    : offset        //set offset
    }
    .done(function(){               //success is deprecated, use done
        $("#result2").html(data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR){          //dump the info to the console (hit f12 to see that in a browser)
        console.log(jqXHR);
        alert("aw damn, something bad happened");
    })
    .always(function(){             //this always happens, doesn't matter if it hits done or fail
        alert("I always happen, done or fail, rain or shine.  You can remove me.");
    })
});
})
```

Examples of pagination links:
    `<a href="#" class="pagination" data-offset="0">1</a> |`
`<a href="#" class="pagination" data-offset="10">2</a> |`
`<a href="#" class="pagination" data-offset="20">3</a> |`
`<a href="#" class="pagination" data-offset="30">4</a>`

I've hard coded 10 as the rows/page (limit), but you can make that whatever.

Here is what the query might look like
`select id, name, price from " + category + " LIMIT 10, 0"`

That would get you the first 10 results of your query.

[See this for MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server) version of limit and offset.

Don't know why you have jQuery aliased to "j", so I left it as dollar sign, but replace the dollar signs with "j" if that is required in your environment.