# SQL, Order by RANDOM and LIMIT not Working?

Tags: sql

Why isn't this query stopping at 15? This is my query.

```
SELECT title, type, profile
FROM playlists
WHERE active='1' AND feature='1' AND type='3' AND user='1'
ORDER BY RAND()
AND LIMIT 15
```

This results in dozens of records, I only want 15 random results to show each time. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: $sql = "SELECT title, type, profile FROM playlists WHERE active='1' AND feature='1' AND type='3' AND user='1' ORDER BY RAND() AND LIMIT 15";                   ------- YES - mysql.....

Comment: do you use mysql?

Comment: this is not standard SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below - you need to remove `AND` before `LIMIT`

```
SELECT title, type, profile FROM playlists WHERE active='1' AND feature='1' 
AND type='3' AND user='1' 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Tried that with no luck... Sorry, I thought I edited that out when I posted, I was trying several things, but officially the "AND" is not in the query...

Comment: how want you to see your order by by- expected output is much more appreciated @Davo

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `AND` before the keyword `LIMIT`.

```
$sql = "SELECT title, type, profile FROM playlists WHERE active='1' AND feature='1' AND type='3' AND user='1' ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 15";
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I edited that out when I posted, I was trying several things, but officially the "AND" is not in the query...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an useful link for randomize the result. Check it [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm).

Your code only works on MySQL. For PostgreSQL and sqlite, use `RANDOM()`. For SQL Server, use `NEWID()`.
For PostgreSQL and sqlite

```
$sql = "SELECT title, type, profile FROM playlists WHERE active='1' AND feature='1' AND type='3' AND user='1' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 15";
```

For SQl Server

```
$sql = "SELECT title, type, profile FROM playlists WHERE active='1' AND feature='1' AND type='3' AND user='1' ORDER BY NEWID() FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY";
```

Notice the difference usage of limit in SQL Server. There is a question for it. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server/9261762#9261762).

Comment: Tried that with no luck... Sorry, I thought I edited that out when I posted, I was trying several things, but officially the "AND" is not in the query...