# Adding page number in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the existing table with one more column PageNo. The PageNo is dynamic value based on the total number of rows in the table. Say for an example I have 12 rows in the table. And while sending output from SQL, the customer want to send 4 rows per each page. So in my table

1. the first 4 rows will be Pageno:1.
2. Second set of 4 rows will be Page no:2

and so on..

Say for an example

```
SET @NoRowsPerPage=4
TotalNumber of rows in the table =12
```

So overall I have 3 pages (12/4) = 3:

Current output is as follows:

| Id | Name | Age | PageNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | sat | 26 | NULL |
| 200 | Apple | 30 | NULL |
| 103 | CHERRY | 26 | NULL |
| 106 | Orange | 26 | NULL |
| 107 | Raspberry | 26 | NULL |
| 109 | Lemon | 36 | NULL |
| 389 | Pineapple | 28 | NULL |
| 107 | MITUN | 26 | NULL |
| 109 | TEMPOR | 26 | NULL |
| 389 | KISN | 26 | NULL |
| 110 | Mandarin | 26 | NULL |
| 111 | BANANAG | 26 | NULL |

Expected output:

| Id | Name | Age | PageNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | sat | 26 | 1 |
| 200 | Apple | 30 | 1 |
| 103 | CHERRY | 26 | 1 |
| 106 | Orange | 26 | 1 |
| 107 | Raspberry | 26 | 2 |
| 109 | Lemon | 36 | 2 |
| 389 | Pineapple | 28 | 2 |
| 107 | MITUN | 26 | 2 |
| 109 | TEMPOR | 26 | 3 |
| 389 | KISN | 26 | 3 |
| 110 | Mandarin | 26 | 3 |
| 111 | BANANAG | 26 | 3 |

Can you please help. The idea is my first select query will fetch only the pageno :1 rows. second select query will pass only pageno:2 values...

Comment: This is likely something like `FLOOR(ROWNUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <something>)/@NoRowsPerPageBased) + 1`, but... what column(s) determine the ordering?

Comment: Don't take this approach. It's always better to do pagination dynamically. Tomorrow if the sort order changes, your column will be of no use. Instead of this use `limit` and `offset`

Comment: Since this is sql server, instead of `limit`/`offset` you use [`offset`/`fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9261762/2221001), which I would agree is better than stamping pagination to a table column.

Comment: Hi JNevill:  As of now no need to order, but can have ProductID or even can insert an identity column(incrementing)  . Can you please give an example on Floor(RowNUMBER)

Comment: When you talk about "the first 4 rows" that implies an order. First 4 ordered by what?

Comment: "No need to order". Then you can do `FLOOR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1)/@NoRowsPerPageBased) + 1` which will just put a row_number() on every record with no ordering. Each time you run it, you may get a different ordering, or you might not, depending on what way the wind is blowing, so to speak.

Comment: @JNevill - Not suitable for pagination as there is no guarantee that the ordering mechanism will be the same between page 1 and page 2 and it would be totally valid for it to give you the exact same rows on "page 2" as you were already given on  "page 1"

Comment: Presumable @MartinSmith OP would stamp the ordering for all rows at once into the table since that's what they are asking to solve for, so it would be pre-decided and consistent. It's not a great idea when `offset`/`fetch` exists, but is sound-ish.

Comment: Ah right. I was just skimming TBH and thought the `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` suggestion was in conjunction with `offset/fetch`. Apologies

Comment: @MartinSmith That is a terrible idea and I sort of love it. Can you do a window function inside `offset` or `fetch`? That would be wild.

Comment: In the `ORDER BY` - https://dbfiddle.uk/iB4KtBKf but not in any of the other components.

Comment: RANK() OVER() could be used, but again this is heavyweight to do what is essentially a client paging problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't take this approach. It's always better to do pagination dynamically. Tomorrow if the sort order changes, your column will be of no use. Instead of this use `limit` and `offset`.

```
Select * from my_table order by id asc limit :pageSize offset :pageNo*:pageSize;
```

Here pageSize and pageNo are parameters taken from the user.

For SQL server, you can use `OFFSET`, `FETCH`, `NEXT`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY
    id 
OFFSET :pageSize*:pageNo ROWS 
FETCH NEXT :pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```